# Videos in beamer inside boxes?

Tags: beamer, diagrams, media9

I'm absolute beginner in bearmer not latex. I would like to add videos insides boxes as the following picture.

[image: here]

How possible is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How possible is that? Very possible! `;-)`

Here is an attempt using `tikz` and `media9`.

The code for the video embedding is taken directly from the [`media9` package manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/media9); I've simply inserted that code into a TikZ `\node` and slightly adjusted the size.

The required media files are `cube.mp4` and `cubeposter.png`, both available from the [`media9` distribution](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/files/).

Place the media files in the same directory as your document (sample code below) and compile with `pdflatex`. Adobe Reader and a suitable Flash Player/Plugin for your operating system are required for the video to be viewable.

The placeholder image (`cubeposter.png`) will be shown. When clicked, the video will begin playing. In viewers not supporting embedded video, only the placeholder image will be shown. Be aware that PDF files like this are not extremely portable.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz,media9}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
  >=latex,
  minimum size=0.5cm,
  block/.style={draw,align=center},
  sum/.style={draw,circle},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,font=\small,auto]
    \node[sum] (S) at (0,0) {};
    \node[block,right=of S] (V1) {%
      \includemedia[
        %activate=onclick, % default
        addresource=cube.mp4,
        flashvars={
          source=cube.mp4
          &autoPlay=true % start playing on activation
          &loop=true
        }
      ]{\includegraphics[height=0.2\linewidth]{cubeposter}}{VPlayer9.swf}%
    };
    \node[block,right=of V1] (q) {};
    \node[block,right=of q] (V2) {Video 2\\Placeholder};
    \draw[<-] (S) node[near start,above left] {$+$} -- +(-1.5,0) node[swap,midway] {$a$};
    \draw (S) -- node {$q(x)$} (V1);
    \draw (V1) -- node {$q$} (q);
    \draw (q) -- (V2);
    \draw (V2) -- +(1.5,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I enable externalize engine, the tikz figure is saved as a pdf. Is it possible to embed this pdf in another latex file? With the video playing? If so, how can I do that?